# Whether Uml file(class diagram) created using rational rose can be used to generate code in Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, import, uml, code-generation

Can the import option for a UML file (class diagram) created using rational rose or staruml be used to generate the code in Netbeans?  And which is better for this option, Netbeans or eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is not anymore providing an UML plugin therefore Eclipse is a better choice today. It is impossible to import Rose models because UML 1.x and the new UML2 is not backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is definitely the better options as Netbeans no longer offers UML support, whereas there are a number of [plugins](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2) for Eclipse.